# Duplicate definition of category in app when using modular headers, Objective-C & Swift in private pod

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

With the introduction of Cocoapods v1.5 allowing Swift static libraries, I've been trying to convert my private pods (originally just Objective-C) to include Swift. I've managed to do this, but I'm left with a warning "Duplicate definition of category" for all categories in the pod.  It may be that I'm doing something rather stupid as modular headers are new to me.

I have two private pods, one is a shared library for development, and the other a shared library for tests. For brevity, I've removed some targets and pod references in the Podfile below.

I have noticed that the number of warnings can go up or down depending upon how I import code from the private pod in the app. Traditionally I have just used: #import "Class.h". Now, when I have tried to use @import ;, the warnings have gone up. Once when I used #import they went down. But not every time.

If I use #import  instead of #import "SomeClass.h", 
 76 more warnings appear.

What am I doing wrong?

What I am finding is that if a category header file is only referred to via a .m file, the warning goes away.

```
source 'https://privatepod.url.com/git/my_podspec'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

use_modular_headers!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def test_pods
  pod 'M13ProgressSuite', '~> 1.2',  :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'AimpTestKit', :path => '../aimptestkit',  :inhibit_warnings => false
  pod 'Quick', :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'Nimble',  :inhibit_warnings => true
end

def common_pods
    pod 'M13ProgressSuite', '~> 1.2',  :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'HockeySDK', :subspecs => ['AllFeaturesLib'],  :inhibit_warnings => true
    pod 'AimpKit', :path => '../aimpkit',  :inhibit_warnings => false
end


target ‘free_app’ do
    common_pods
    target 'free_app Tests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        test_pods
    end

end

target ‘paid_app’ do
    common_pods
    target 'PaidAppTests' do
        inherit! :search_paths
        test_pods
    end
end


target 'LogicTests' do
    #no host app
    inherit! :search_paths
    common_pods
    test_pods
end
```

This is the podspec for the shared library (again I've removed some superfluous stuff for brevity):

```
{
    "name": "AimpKit",
    "version": "3.0.1",
    "summary": "AimpKit library",
    "static_framework": true,
    "platforms": {
        "ios": "9.0"
    },
    "source": {
    "git": "https://privatepod.url.com/git/my_podspec",
    "branch": "master"
  },
    "source_files": "aimpkit/**/*.{h,m,swift}",
    "resources": "resources/**/*.{xib,xcassets,storyboard,bundle,png,mp4}",
    "requires_arc": [
       "aimpkit/arc/**/*.{h,m,swift}"
  ],
     "frameworks": [
        "CFNetwork", 
        "Foundation", 

    ],
    "dependencies": {

    "HockeySDK/AllFeaturesLib": [

    ],


  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to fixing this was to ensure that in class headers did not refer to a category header. Thus a class did not in its .h file import a category header. Moving all those category header file imports (big job) to the .m of each class file resolved this issue.

Also, had the issue that named categories declared inside a class header were also declared duplicate. Presumably because the class header was being invoked by other headers and the category definition in the class was being seen multiple times. The resolution here was to remove the name from the category definition.

All the category header files are referenced within a framework header (e.g ) surrounded by conditional statements so only parsed once (e.g #ifndef AimpKit_h #define AimpKit_h #endif).